# How to automatically rearrange code within Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: c#, rider

I'm evaluating Jetbrains Rider 2017.1.1 for a C# project. I need to automatically rearrange code based on specific rules (like moving private methods to the bottom, public methods to the top, ...). I used this feature with IntelliJ IDEA.

Within Rider the "Code -> Rearrange Code" option is available but greyed out. Did I miss to activate it somewhere or is it just not available yet? If so, is there an appropriate formatting plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for Rider 2017.2 EAP3, the UI for code arrangement setting is not implemented. However, Rider respects ReSharper settings. If you have configured File Layout in ReSharper and saved it to a team-shared layer, then running Code Cleanup in Rider will apply your layout.

Comment: Worth noting that there's a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2522) to vote up.